# What is going on with this CSV file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file that is for some reason creating unnecessary Unnamed columns any time I do something.

Two first lines from said CSV file before anything is done to it:

```
Date,Type,Action,Symbol,Instrument Type,Description,Value,Quantity,Average Price,Commissions,Fees,Multiplier,Underlying Symbol,Expiration Date,Strike Price,Call or Put
2020-04-29T06:37:14-0400,Receive Deliver,BUY_TO_OPEN,USO1  201016C00014500,Equity Option,Reverse split: Open 2 USO1  201016C00014500,-10,2,-5,,0,100,USO,10/16/2020,14.5,CALL
```

Note how there are no extraneous commas. When I read the file as is, it seems to have `Date` as the index, but I can't reach it. Gives me an error with `['Date']` and `[0]` and also `.index` So, I created a new column and made it the index. All seems well. I run a function that changes the `Date` values to `timestamp` and also reversed the index. Yet, when I try to reset the index with `drop=True` or `inplace=True` or anything else I can think of, I am getting an unnamed column set as the index, with the index column being pushed to the end.

```
,Date,Type,Action,Symbol,Instrument Type,Description,Value,Quantity,Average Price,Commissions,Fees,Multiplier,Underlying Symbol,Expiration Date,Strike Price,Call or Put,ind
0,2019-12-10 17:00:00,Money Movement,,,,ACH DEPOSIT,"1,500.00",0,,,0.0,,,,,,709
```

This is the current snippet I have:

```
import pandas as pd

# set csv file as constant
TRADER_READER = pd.read_csv('TastyTrades.csv')
TRADER_READER['ind'] = TRADER_READER.index

# change date format, make date into timestamp object, set date as index, write changes to csv file
def clean_date():
    TRADER_READER['Date'] = TRADER_READER['Date'].replace({'T': ' ', '-0500': '', '-0400': ''}, regex=True)
    TRADER_READER['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(TRADER_READER['Date'], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    reversed_index = TRADER_READER.iloc[::-1].reset_index(drop=True)
    reversed_index.to_csv('TastyTrades.csv')
```

Comment: Did you try to reduce the code keeping the issue?

Comment: If I don't use `TRADER_READER['ind'] = TRADER_READER.index`, I can't run `clean_date()`. This wasn't an issue before but now it is.